# Denormalisation approach of datamodel like facebook

Tags: database, elasticsearch

I was going through the Elasticsearch tutorial then I had the question in my mind,
How can I approach the denormalisation of the datamodel of let's say facebook?
Can I put all facebook data in ElasticSearch and do not use any relation database? When I have the same kind of traffic as facebook has?
Or do I still need to have the database, and if yes for what reason(s)?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch itself says that, its a distributed restful search and analytics engine. So when you see both search and analytics we can derive that its is equivalent to a NoSQL database.

Your question is right and we also had this question in our mind when we thought of using elasticsearch in our project. We work on enterprise integration platform which works similar to stack overflow where people in company ask questions, post queries and answers, tag them appropriately. All this is done as part of Knowledge Management initiative. So when we looked at elasticsearch, we know that this can fulfill our needs of simplifying the issues that we have because of normalization of database. The fetch of data became so costly and need lot of joins to reach to data someone is looking for. And this query became so costly, when we realize that we can't create indexes on some of the fields due to our database structure limitations. So this normalization which has eventually become overnormalization was killing the performance.

We looked at elasticsearch and its case studies. What gave us confidence is that stack overflow use it. So, that is where we decided to do a pilot and try it out. We used it as a NoSQL store where we store data in de-normalized fashion.

We have entities with its attributes as entities in itself. Sometimes those attributes can also be multi-valued. We assessed our data and created appropriate [mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) where we have stored everything in Lucene index and indexed only those fields with not_analyzed property on which we wanted to apply our filter i.e. the where clauses of query. It really improved the performance of fetch as we are now supporting the complex queries which require multiple concurrent filter with a mixture of [terms](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-filter.html) and [range](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) filter. Achieving such performance by applying complex filters as where clauses in SQL queries is a nightmare for us. But elasticsearch really saved the day.

When you have same kind of traffic as facebook, my vote is that you can definitely go for elasticsearch as it can scale well. You can add more machines at any point of time. You can do complex queries without affecting performance yet achieving the good throughput.

One more important point I want to say is that elasticsearch is not a replacement of SQL. you can't give away with SQL. You need it for preserving the ACID property for some of your data like use authentication and access control. You can blend the SQL with elasticsearch like we did and try out some cool stuff of your own. Now, how to do it and what should i put in elasticsearch can only be determined when you analyze and see your data. But one thing I am sure of is that it will not let you down.